# Asp .net MVC - [Live_Website]/sitemap.xml Returns "404 - File or directory not found."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, sitemap

i created a ActionResult and sitemapProvider class which returns sitemap.xml result for my company's website. It is perfectly works on '[localhost]/sitemap.xml'. It gives me what i need but when i put the code on live web server and type 'www.[website]/sitemap.xml', i get "404 - File or directory not found." error. How can i solve this issue?

Function =>

```
public ActionResult SitemapXml()
        {
            SitemapProvider provider = new SitemapProvider();

            var sitemapNodes = provider.GetSitemapNodes(this.Url);
            string xml = provider.GetSitemapDocument(sitemapNodes);

            return this.Content(xml, "Xml", Encoding.UTF8);
        }
```

Route Config =>
`routes.MapRoute("sitemap", "sitemap.xml", new { controller = "Main", action = "SitemapXml" });`

Web Config =>

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="SitemapXml" path="sitemap.xml" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Project has 2 web.config files, i added  both configs. On localhost is working. On live web site is not working. I cant figure it out.
I also tried create a new route not including ".xml" part like
`routes.MapRoute("sitemap2", "sitemap", new { controller = "Main", action = "SitemapXml" });`
It worked fine on live web site it gived me sitemap.xml but 'www.[web_site]/sitemap.xml' is not worked